# millis string format in java

Tags: java, string, format, decimal

I have this code:

```
  public String calculateHoursFromMilliSeconds(long totalMilliSeconds) {
        long totalSeconds = totalMilliSeconds / 1000;
        long milli = totalMilliSeconds % 1000;
        long hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
        long minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
        long seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        return String.format("%02d:%02d.%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, milli);
    }
```

however

for input 412 millis

i get output `00:00.004` instead of `00:00.412`

for input 60412 millis

i get output `01:00.004` instead of `01:00.412`

Comment: I know this is not answering your question, but isn't [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) essentially doing what you want?

Comment: You are calculationg the miliseconds part which is 1/1000 from a second. So this code works as expected.. It should not be 400 but 004.

Comment: For `60412`, I get the output `00:01.000`.

Comment: no, I'm dealing with time span. not date

Comment: Either I can't see or you have 4 parameters and only 3 on list? `return String.format("%02d:%02d.%03d", hours, minutes, seconds,milli);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one less `%02d` in the format string. Try this:

```
return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, milli);
//                     HH : MM : SS . milli
```

[Sample output](https://ideone.com/ZCKQgu):

```
412:   00:00:00.412
60412: 00:01:00.412
```

---

Alternatively, remove the `hours` if it is `0`. Add the following condition:

```
if(hours == 0) return String.format("%02d:%02d.%03d", minutes, seconds, milli);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have tried to get format `%02d:%02d.%03d` (here you have given 3) with 4 parameters. So you missed the `milli`. Instead of `milli` to be formatted, the `second` was formatted

Code should be :

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, milli)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you interested to convert Epoch to java readable format do this:

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (epoch*1000));
```

or get one by one using calendar:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(millisec*1000);
    int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

etc

Comment: The fields `HOUR`, `SECOND`, `MINUTE` and `MILLISECOND` would have been more relevant to the current problem. But still, good thinking to use a `Calendar` to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
public String calculateHoursFromMilliSeconds(long totalMilliSeconds) {
    long totalSeconds = totalMilliSeconds / 1000;
    long milli = totalMilliSeconds % 1000;
    long hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    long minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
    long seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###");
    formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    String millisStr = formatter.format(milli);

    return String.format("%02d:%02d."+millisStr, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: No it's not, you're still missing the seconds since you don't have enough format specifiers. See John's answer.